# Involution on semigroups with identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

I'm trying to understand the following: Let $S$ be a semigroup. By an *involution* on $S$ we mean a map $* : S \to S$ satisfying for all $a,b\in S$

1. $(ab)^*=b^*a^*$
2. $(a^*)^*=a $

My problem is the following. Why if $S$ has an identity we must have $a^*=a$ for all $a\in S$?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems false. Consider the complex numbers with multiplication as binary operation and complex conjugation as involution. Maybe you mean to ask why I*=I, if I denotes the identity? Observe that (I*)a=((a*)I)* =(a*)* =a=(a*)* =(I(a*))* =a(I*).

Comment: I saw this statement in a paper and i'm trying to see why they wrote it. since every group is a semigroup and if you take the inversion map as your involution. you can see that it is not the case that $a^*=a^{-1}=a$ for all $a$ in the group.

Comment: In which paper did you see this statement?